# php - Group By Column in Do.. While Looping

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I know this is very basic ... but unfortunately i can doing with my head for now, and **this not my homework** this is logical needed in my application,, my someone tell the clue ... here the code i have..

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$header = 0;
$hitungLoopingObat= 9;
do{
  $remainder = ($i+1) % 5;
  $head = ($remainder+$i) % 5; // output: 1 .. 1
  // $head = (1+$remainder) % 5; // output: 2 .. 2
  // $head = (1+$header) % $hitungLoopingObat; // output: 1 .. 6

  if($remainder == 1)
    echo "Header " .$head. "\n";

  echo "Konten Ke " . $i . "\n";
  if( $remainder == 0) {
    echo "new line \n";
  }
  $i++;
  $header++;
}
while($i <= $hitungLoopingObat || $header <= $hitungLoopingObat);
if($remainder > 0){
  $loncat = (5 - $remainder)+1;
  for($j=0; $j<$loncat; $j++)
  {
    echo "Sisa New Line " .$loncat. "\n";
  }
}
```

i'm testing here: https://3v4l.org/SkBAX

the output of header still 'header 1' .. 'header 1' not increase .. to header 1 ... header 2..

any clue very appreciate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this variable called `$header` that seems effectively to be unused (it has exactly the same value as `$i`) you may as well make it do something instead. Get rid of the `$header++` at the end of the loop and this line:

```
$head = ($remainder+$i) % 5;
```

and change this code:

```
if($remainder == 1)
    echo "Header " .$head. "\n";
```

to:

```
if($remainder == 1)
    echo "Header " . $header++ . "\n";
```

Now given that `$i` and `$header` were doing exactly the same thing in your loop, it's not clear whether you want to terminate at `$i > $hitungLoopingObat` or `$header > $hitungLoopingObat` or both. So since this change affects the behaviour of `$header` you might need to change this line:

```
while($i <= $hitungLoopingObat || $header <= $hitungLoopingObat);
```

to:

```
while($i <= $hitungLoopingObat);
```

Final loop code:

```
do {
  $remainder = ($i+1) % 5;

  if($remainder == 1)
    echo "Header " . $header++ . "\n";

  echo "Konten Ke " . $i . "\n";
  if( $remainder == 0 && $i < $hitungLoopingObat) {
    echo "new line \n";
  }
  $i++;
}
while ($i <= $hitungLoopingObat);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, i missing .. this logical looping! Thanks sir.. this link is work now ..

https://3v4l.org/d9o7R

Comment: btw, how about stop print "New line" for the last, if the header is stop increasing.. i'm using $hitungLoopingObat = 9 example ... i hope you give me the clue sir ... thanks.

Comment: See my edit. That should solve the "New line" problem.

Comment: If it solved the problem please mark the answer accepted so other users can find it. thanks.

Comment: i can't accepted i'm new for posting in stackoverflow.

Comment: Sure you can you just click the tick under the voting buttons.